# Getting milliseconds from two different methods of date

Tags: javascript, date, gettime

Why there is the difference between these two ways of getting milliseconds

```js
gigasecond = inputDate => {
  console.log(inputDate)
  console.log(inputDate.getTime())     //1303689600000
  console.log(
    Date.UTC(inputDate.getFullYear(), 
             inputDate.getMonth(),
             inputDate.getDate(),
             inputDate.getHours(), 
             inputDate.getMinutes(),
             inputDate.getSeconds())); //1303709400000
};

gigasecond(new Date(Date.UTC(2011, 3, 25)))
```

Comment: The second is with timezone applied. In my case 2 hours from UTC

Comment: Don't forget milliseconds. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getHours()` method returns the hour for the specified date, according to local time. Use `getUTCHours()` instead.

```js
gigasecond = inputDate => {
  console.log(inputDate)
  console.log(inputDate.getHours(), inputDate.getUTCHours())
  console.log(inputDate.getTime()) //1303689600000
  console.log(
    Date.UTC(inputDate.getFullYear(),
      inputDate.getUTCMonth(),
      inputDate.getUTCDate(),
      inputDate.getUTCHours(),
      inputDate.getUTCMinutes(),
      inputDate.getUTCSeconds()
    )
  ); //1303709400000
};

gigasecond(new Date(Date.UTC(2011, 3, 25)))
```